# Node.js webhook/event system

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webhooks

Thoughts on how you guys would/do handle this... If you need to send a webhook when something happens. Say, when a customer registers.. How would you guarantee that a webhook has been sent for it? You couldn't just have the code send the webhook after the registration happens, as what if the server crashes right after registration but before/during the webhook request.. If you were using MongoDB, I guess you could listen to the oplog and see what a registration record is inserted, but then what if your oplog monitoring script crashes.. I thought about storing locally a file that records the last successfully processed timestamp but then you're really limiting yourself to processing the oplog one at a time, which on an active DB could really get behind.

I thought about using a queuing/task system but then what if the request to store the task in the queue crashes..

Maybe store a field on the registration DB record that says if the webhook has been sent yet, send it once the registration happens and have a script that checks every once in awhile for webhooks that failed to send within a certain amount of time?

Just trying to think of the best way to make sure a webhook is actually sent for a particular event.

Comment: Also, yes... you can catch errors or uncaught exceptions and handle them properly. I'm more concerned about the instances of an uncatchable error, like an actual server/host crash. You can't detect that in your code and handle it. Or what if the network goes out, you could store a cache locally but what if for some reason the disk can be written to.

Comment: I thought about maybe storing a log.. something that follows the progress of each transaction.. For instance.. 1) Registration started... 2) Registration completed... 3) Webhook started ... 4) Webhook completed.. That way each step is logged and if a step fails to complete in a set amount of time, a monitoring script can resume where it left off.

Comment: Assuming it is a post-event webhook. Create a db entry for scheduling the webhook and remove it after its done successfully. You could even store the response there for later refernce.

Comment: Sure, until the entry to schedule the webhook fails.